# HTML page encoding problems

Tags: javascript, html, encoding, utf-8

I am having some trouble with a website I am creating, I am using Adobe Dreamweaver to just write code in, not using its visual builder.
I have code like this in the file:

```
<button type="button" onclick="addToCart("box")">Add to cart</button>
```

But when I view this in Firefox and Internet explorer, when I inspect the page using Firefox the code turns to this:

```
<button pens")"="" onclick="addToCart(" type="button">
```

The strange thing is when I view the page source in Firefox it shows up correct.

I did try to also declare the encoding with the meta tag as UTF-8, but no luck (Yes I saved it as this before hand in just notepad).

What can I do? EDIT: Im ashamed of myself for not seeing this myself, but in my opinion Dreamweaver isn't very good as an IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest fix is to use single quotes in your javascript:

```
<button type="button" onclick="addToCart('box')">Add to cart</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with encoding. Like Munter says, use single quotes.

Viewing the source just shows the code you typed; If you inspect the element you see what the browser thinks you mean, because the code you wrote is invalid.